# I Want a Button that hide the div and restore it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to create a button that will hide each ticket and one general button that will restore them all.

this is the Code:

```
return (
  <ul className="tickets">
    {filteredTickets.map((ticket) => (
      <li key={ticket.id} className="ticket">
        <h5 className="headline">{ticket.headline}</h5>
        <p className="text">{ticket.text}</p>
        <footer>
          <div className="data">
            By {ticket.address} | {new Date(ticket.time).toLocaleString()}
          </div>
        </footer>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: Filtered tickets is an array that you can manipulate? What i mean is that you can add a visible boolean atrribute to each element of the array and play with it. Other thing you can do is play with 2 states, one for filter data and another one with all the data to restore. In the button you can add an onclick event and a hideItem passing the id or index

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of what you want!
you have to replace myFunction() for your button and myDIV into your element that you want to hide it!

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

for react =
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true)
here is for button
<button onlick={() =>setVisible(!visible)}>hide/show

Comment: its show me this error:
Type '{ children: string; onclick: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Property 'onclick' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'.  TS2322

Comment: ok then instead of using funtion use useState for react and write the code like this const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true), and for onCLick button write onlick={() =>setVisible(!visible) } , and use  visible as a logic to hide or show your element

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo in JS, modify to what you want exactly

```
<ul class="ticket">
<li>
        <p>hey, I'm a P</p>
        <div class="data">I'm a Div</div>
      </li>
</ul>
.hide {display:none}

const generalBtn = document.getElementById(`btn`);
const divContainer = document.querySelector(`.ticket`);
const eachDiv = divContainer.getElementsByClassName(`data`);
generalBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  [...eachDiv].forEach((div) => {
    div.classList.toggle(`hide`);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution in your case but as mentioned in the comments, it needs to manipulate the `filteredTickets` array.

You need to add a property/value to each item of `filteredTickets` to track or change their state. For example, it can be `isVisible` property which is a boolean with `false` or `true` value.

Now, `isVisible` value will determine the behavior. let's modify the ticket:

```
const handleHideTicket = (id) => {
  // find selected ticket and ​change its visibility
 ​const updatedFilterdTickets = filteredTikcets.map(ticket => (ticket.id === id ? {...ticket, isVisible: false} : ticket))
 // now the updatedFilterdTickets need to be set in your state or general state like redux or you need to send it to the server throw a API calling.
}


return (
 ​<ul className="tickets">
   ​{filteredTickets.filter(ticket => ticket.isVisible).map((ticket) => (
     ​<li key={ticket.id} className="ticket">
       ​<h5 className="headline">{ticket.headline}</h5>
       ​<p className="text">{ticket.text}</p>
       ​<footer>
         ​<div className="data">
           ​By {ticket.address} | {new Date(ticket.time).toLocaleString()}
         ​</div>
         // add a button to control visibility of each ticket
         ​<button onClick={() => handleHideTicket (ticket.id)}> click to hid / show </button>
       ​</footer>
     ​</li>
   ​))}
 ​</ul>
);
```

##### Explanation:

a new `button` added to each ticket and pass the `handleHideTicket`  handler to it. If the user clicks on this button, the handler finds that ticket and sets the `isVisible` property to the `false`.

On the other hand, we can remove the hidden tickets by applying a simple `filter` method before `map` method. so only visible tickets will be displayed.

Now, create a general button to show all the tickets. In this case, you need a handler function that sets all ticket's `isVisible` value to `true`

```
const handleShowAllTickets = () => {
  const updatedFilteredTickets = filteredTickets.map(ticket => ({...ticket, isVisible: true}))
  // now put the updatedFilteredTickets in your general store/post an API call/ update state 
}
```

**Note:** as I mentioned in the code's comments, you need to update your `filteredTickets` array after changing via handlers to reflect the changes in your elements.

Comment: I have tried your solution , and it shows me this error : 

./src/App.tsx
SyntaxError: C:\projects\fed-entry-level-exam\client\src\App.tsx: Unexpected character '​' (37:3)

  35 | 
  36 |   const handleHideTicket = (id) => {
> 37 |    ​const updatedFilterdTickets = filteredTickets.map
     |    ^
  38 |   (ticket => ticket.id === id ? {...ticket, isVisible: false} : ticket)
  39 |  }
  40 |

Comment: Please check the code again, I've update my code snipet and added the "(" for retrnuning from the map @daniel

Comment: ./src/App.tsx
Syntax error: ';' expected (75:10)

Comment: I can't debug in this way,  forget for the implementation, it may not be the exact code you need in your project, I expected you to get my idea and procedure to achieve that @daniel since you are new to React, I've tried to explain each line of codes with comments inside the codes and an extra explanation to clarify the answer. feel free to ask any question about the above answer. please read it carefully and try to go through step by step.